# can we store downloaded files into an image which acts as a folder for downloaded files

Tags: android

I had an image which has been downloaded from the server.Now,I want this image to be as folder to store other downloaded files into it dynamically..

Is it possible to store the downloaded files into image?

can we use an image as folder ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not store one image into other image, means your image is not going to behave as a folder. Instead, you can make external folder in `/mnt/sdcard/path_to_your_image_folder` and this folder can behave as a container for your downloaded images.

Comment: Hello YuDroid Happy to see your response quickly can't we save those images into internal memory? If possible what will be the path then @YuDroid

Comment: To store those images in internal memory, you need to give data/data/your.package/your_image_folder. Doing this will increase your application size. So its better to store these downloaded images on SD card instead of internal memory. Hope you got this.. :)

Comment: http://android-codes-examples.blogspot.in/2011/09/image-and-content-is-populated-from.html This may help you getting your things done..